# Discord Bot - Setting up an embed table/list with contents split into sections

Tags: javascript, bots, embed, discord

I'm still learning Javascript and such, getting into discord.js so I'm pretty sure the code I'm inputting is absolutely wrong and definitely in need of work.

Essentially what I'm looking to do is split up a command's arguments and separate them into new lines of an embed.

For example, if I was to do: `!results "Result 1" "Result 2" "Result 3"` it would output into an embed like table:

```
RESULTS:
```

```
Result 1
```

```
Result 2
```

```
Result 3
```

Instead, my output keeps coming out as:

[Image of what happens in discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba9Jm.png)

I have tried various different things from searching on google, but I can't seem to find the thing that I need.

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "results",
    category: "info",
    description: "posts results in embed",
    usage: "<mention, id>",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
            if (message.deletable) message.delete();

        let [result1, result2, result3, result4, result5, result6, result7] = args;

        if (!args[0])
            return message.channel.send("Please provide Result 1.").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        if (!args[1])
            return message.channel.send("Please provide Result 2.").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        if (!args[2])
            return message.channel.send("Please provide Result 3.").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        if (!args[3])
            return message.channel.send("Please provide Result 4.").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        if (!args[4])
            return message.channel.send("Please provide Result 5.").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        if (!args[5])
            return message.channel.send("Please provide Result 6.").then(m => m.delete(5000));
        if (!args[6])
            return message.channel.send("Please provide Result 7.").then(m => m.delete(5000));

        const channel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "cards")

        if (!channel)
                return message.channel.send("Couldn't find a `#cards` channel").then(m => m.delete(5000));

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTimestamp()
            .setAuthor("Posted by GM:", (message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL))
            .setTitle("**TestTitle**")
            .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL)
            .setDescription(`**__Results!__**`)
            .addField(`**> Result 1:** ${result1}`)
            .addField(`**> Result 2:** ${result2}`)
            .addField(`**> Result 3:** ${result3}`)
            .addField(`**> Result 4:** ${result4}`)
            .addField(`**> Result 5:** ${result5}`)
            .addField(`**> Result 6:** ${result6}`)            
            .addField(`**> Result 7:** ${result7}`);


        return channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have made some progress, this is the most recent code and this is the output:

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMkko.png)

Comment: Post code so someone can try to take a look at what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a field, which requires both a title and value. But you are only giving it a value.
I'd recommend just using the description field and separating your stuff by new lines. It will often times look better. Be sure to keep in mind that the description field is only up to [2048 characters](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-limits) though.

Here's a guide you can take a look at:
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview

Comment: Thank you!  I totally understand that now and managed to figure all that out. What I'm also wanting to find out is args from the command to be split up from inside "quotations"
For example, running the command !results "result 1" "result 2"

I'd want "result 1" to be arg(0). Etc

Comment: I don't know if Discord.js has some prebuilt method for parsing input into arguments. Would recommend looking into that first. If not, maybe a regex with capture groups could do the trick. A simple regex like `"(.+)"` could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse the arguments you probably have to create a new delimiter, use a comma or something.

```
    const prefix = "!";
    if (message.author.bot) return;  // exit processing if author is a bot
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;  // exit processing if message is not a bot command

    const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
    const args = commandBody.split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === "ping"){
        message.channel.send("Hello");
    }
    if(command === "test"){
        message.channel.send("it is a good day for testing!");
        if (args.length > 0) {
            message.channel.send("Hello " + args[0]);
        }
    }
```

You would change the .split(' ') to something like a comma .split(',')

So the user would enter !test,myName
the the bot would reply:

```
it is a good dat for testing
Hello myName
```